# Am I eclectic for listening to Pink Floyd

Tags: rock, genre, guitar, prog-rock

Currently, at work, I've got into a debate with someone who isn't very well versed in the nuances of music. They detest Pink Floyd and argue with my claim that I have eclectic music tastes because I listen to Pink Floyd.  They say I like Pink Floyd *due to them being popular*. Whereas, I, someone who is extremely eclectic in all walks of life, strongly disagree with their stance.  I listen to Pink Floyd *on the basis that they were the originators of psychedelic rock*.

Please can we all put a stop to this charlatan and agree that Pink Floyd are both incredibly excellent and I am exceedingly eclectic for listening to them?

Comment: Yes, as per Dekkadeci's answer, we're going to need more information to be able to answer this question (on a similar note: 'incredibly excellent' is subjective - I think if it were just "excellent", as in "excelling in their genre", the question would be answerable).

Comment: You might have eclectic musical tastes, but you seem to be misusing the word. Maybe you mean your music tastes are "elite."

Comment: If by "eclectic", you are asking "am I clown-pants", then yes.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger Thats not very helpful

Answer (score 3):

Here are dictionary definitions I found for the adjective "eclectic":

"deriving ideas, style, or taste from a broad and diverse range of sources"

(the first definition found in today's Google search for the word "eclectic")

"composed of elements drawn from various sources"

"selecting what appears to be best in various doctrines, methods, or styles"

(both from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eclectic))

This means that I need to know what other music you listen to--if any--before I can determine whether you have eclectic music tastes.

If all you listen to is Pink Floyd--or any one band or composer--then I cannot call your taste in music eclectic. If all you listen to is one genre of music, then I still hesitate to call your taste in music eclectic.

But if you listen to a wide variety of bands, composers, and genres of music, then I believe I can safely call your taste in music eclectic.

Comment: +1 for a great effort at giving a reasonable answer to a ludicrous question.